# Assign an array of int (only one element) to an integer in c

Tags: c, syntax, variable-assignment

I've seen on a web page that we could do this:

```
int k = {5};
```

When I try it myself I found that this works in C programming and the value of `k` is `5`.

- q1: Why could we assign an array of integer (even if there is only one element) to a variable of integer type, shoudn't there be some errors?
- q2: What is this type of assignment used for? (in which situation and why we use it or perhaps we won't use it anymore?)

Comment: Why do you think `{5}` is an array of one element?  Why cannot it be a structure copy of just one element equal to five?  The reason for that is historical.  It was allowed by the compiler of K&R.

Comment: By the way, that's no type of assignment.  It is **a declaration with an initializer**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't an array, C syntax simply permits this. Both of these are equivalent:

```
int k = 5;
int k = {5};
```

As seen in the syntax rules for initialization<sup>1</sup>,
initializer can be an assignment-expression, which corresponds to:

```
int k = 5;
```

The initializer can also be an {initializer-list}, which can be an initializer, which can be an assignment-expression:

```
int k = {5};
```

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.7.9 Initialization Syntax 1.)
initializer:
    assignment-expression
    { initializer-list }
    { initializer-list , }

initializer-list:
    designation opt initializer
    initializer-list , designation opt initializer

Answer (score 3):

`int k = {5};` is a perfectly legal way to initialise a scalar, although it doesn't really express your *intention* very well. Because of that, a good compiler might warn you.

But do note that brace initialisation to zero `{0}` is idiomatic. (Although in C++, I prefer to use `{}`).

Comment: But I used `gcc` with option `-Wall` but there are no warnings.

Comment: Hum, it certainly *used* to warn you. I wonder if they switched off the warning since too many folk complained about it warning about `{0}`!

Comment: @Bathsheba Why would it warn if it is perfectly defined? Maybe you used a C++ compiler, or some obscure flags?

Comment: "it doesn't really express your intention very well"

Comment: If the intention is to initialize a variable, then both variants express it really well.

Comment: I put it in the same class as `while (1)` and assignment within conditionals. Although I do the latter all the time ;-)

Comment: @SWIIWII, probably it depends of the actual standard you are using to compile.